# Erro "ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes"

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Estou recebendo esse erro:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "geraEstatistica.py", line 148, in 
>       cnplot = map.contour(x,y,resultado,clevs,cmap=plt.cm.jet)
>     File "/home/caio/anaconda3/envs/showcast2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/basemap/**init**.py", line 543, in with_transform
>       return plotfunc(self,x,y,data,*args,**kwargs)
>     File "/home/caio/anaconda3/envs/showcast2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/basemap/**init**.py", line 3569, in contour
>       mask = np.logical_or(ma.getmaskarray(data),xymask)
>   ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (97,153) (2,2)

Quando rodo o seguinte script python:

```
  # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from netCDF4 import Dataset
#from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import inset_axes # Add a child inset axes to this existing axes.
from datetime import datetime, timedelta                     # Library to convert julian day to dd-mm-yyyy
#from cpt_convert import loadCPT                              # Import the CPT convert function
#from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap        # Linear interpolation for color maps
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt                              # Plotting library
#import matplotlib.colors                                     # Matplotlib colors
import numpy as np                                           # Scientific computing with Python
#import cartopy, cartopy.crs as ccrs                          # Plot maps
#import cartopy.io.shapereader as shpreader                   # Import shapefiles
#import time as t                                             # Time access and conversion
import math                                                  # Import math
#from matplotlib.image import imread                          # Read an image from a file into an array
import os                                                    # Miscellaneous operating system interfaces
#import sys                                                   # Import the "system specific parameters and functions" module
#from cartopy.feature.nightshade import Nightshade            # Draws a polygon where there is no sunlight for the given datetime.
#from html_update import update                               # Update the HTML animation
from remap import remap                                      # Import the Remap function
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap 
#from  netCDF4 import Dataset as open_ncfile
import re
global extent_
global lat
global lon
dpi = 100



def interpreta(path): #interpreta os dados da matriz ACMF Clear Sky Mask

    #start = t.time()
    #nc = open_ncfile('netsacmf_jan_2020/'+str(path))

    #print(nc.variables)


    # Image path
    path = "netsacmf_jan_2020/"+str(path)+"_SEC"

    # Remove the composite id
    path_proc = path[:-4]

    # Read the image
    file = Dataset(path_proc)

    # Read the satellite
    satellite = getattr(file, 'platform_ID')

    # Read the main variable
    variable = list(file.variables.keys())[0]

    # Read the product name
    prod_name = getattr(file, 'title')

    # Desired resolution
    resolution = 8

    # Read the resolution
    band_resolution_km = getattr(file, 'spatial_resolution')
    band_resolution_km = float(band_resolution_km[:band_resolution_km.find("km")])

    # Division factor to reduce image size
    f = math.ceil(float(resolution / band_resolution_km))

    #print(resolution)
    #print(band_resolution_km)
    #print(f)

    # Read the central longitude
    longitude = file.variables['goes_imager_projection'].longitude_of_projection_origin

    # Read the semi major axis
    a = file.variables['goes_imager_projection'].semi_major_axis

    # Read the semi minor axis
    b = file.variables['goes_imager_projection'].semi_minor_axis

    # Calculate the image extent
    h = file.variables['goes_imager_projection'].perspective_point_height
    x1 = file.variables['x_image_bounds'][0] * h
    x2 = file.variables['x_image_bounds'][1] * h
    y1 = file.variables['y_image_bounds'][1] * h
    y2 = file.variables['y_image_bounds'][0] * h

    # Reading the file time and date
    add_seconds = int(file.variables['time_bounds'][0])
    date = datetime(2000,1,1,12) + timedelta(seconds=add_seconds)
    date_formated = date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M UTC')
    date_file = date.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M')
    year = date.strftime('%Y')
    month = date.strftime('%m')
    day = date.strftime('%d')
    hour = date.strftime('%H')
    minutes = date.strftime('%M')

    # Choose the visualization extent (min lon, min lat, max lon, max lat)
    extent_ = [float("-54.0"), float("-25.0"), float("-43.0"), float("-18.0")]

    # Call the reprojection funcion
    grid = remap(path_proc, variable, extent_, resolution, h, a, b, longitude, x1, y1, x2, y2)

    # Read the data returned by the function
    data = grid.ReadAsArray()

    # Convert from int16 to uint16
    data = data.astype(np.float64)
    return data


print('- Mapa de janeiro 2020 - cobertura de nuvem - \n Script iniciado! \n gerando matrizes binárias... \n calculando soma de matrizes... ')
global arquivos;
global soma;
soma = np.array([], dtype = float)
for arquivo in os.walk('netsacmf_jan_2020/'): #lê o diretório que contém os nets e transforma em listas com os nomes dos arquivos
    arquivos = list(arquivo[2])

for arq in arquivos:
    if not re.search('aux.xml', arq):
        net_receptus = interpreta(arq)  #manda para a função interpreta para realizar a leitura do nets e transformar na matriz binária net_receptus
        if (len(soma) == 0): 
            soma = net_receptus
        else:
            soma = np.add(soma,net_receptus)


print("calculando estatística final de janeiro...")

qttd = len(arquivo[2])

resultado = (soma / qttd)

lat = np.array([90, -90], dtype = float)
lon = np.array([0, 357.5], dtype = float)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(1100/dpi, 1100/dpi), dpi=dpi)
ax  = fig.add_axes([0.1,0.1,0.8,0.9])
map = Basemap(projection='cyl',llcrnrlat= -90.,urcrnrlat= 90.,
              resolution='c',  llcrnrlon=-180.,urcrnrlon=180.)
map.drawcoastlines()
map.drawstates()
map.drawcountries()

map.drawparallels(np.arange( -90., 90.,30.),labels=[1,0,0,0],fontsize=10)
map.drawmeridians(np.arange(-180.,180.,30.),labels=[0,0,0,1],fontsize=10)

x, y = map(*np.meshgrid(lon,lat))
clevs = np.arange(0,100,1)
cnplot = map.contour(x,y,resultado,clevs,cmap=plt.cm.jet)
plt.title('Mapa de indice de combertura de nuvens - Estado de São Paulo - Janeiro 2020')

plt.show()
plt.savefig('mapa_de_indice_de_cobertura_de_nuvens.png', bbox_inches='tight', dpi=dpi)
```

O objetivo desse script é plotar a matriz resultados, que é a matriz soma dividido pela quantidade de arquivos netCDF's com dados de cobertura de nuvens lidos. A matriz soma é a soma de todas as matrizes binárias que são geradas pelos arquivos netCDF's.

[[0,1,0,1,1,0]] + [[0,1,0,0,1,1]] + ....... = [[20,40,0,20,60,10]] / quantidade de matrizes binárias ou quantidade de arquivos netCDFs = matriz resultado com porcentagens.

estou tentando plotar essa matriz resultado com as porcentagens em um mapa que fique parecido com a imagem abaixo (só que estou fazendo para o mapa do Estado de SP):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

para isso estou utilizando a função countr() e countrf() do matplotlib. mas continuo recebendo esse traceback.

estou utilizando os arquivos netCDF's com ACMF com a mascara de cobertura de nuvens disponibilizados através do AWS da amazon.

são vários arquivos desse: OR_ABI-L2-ACMF-M6_G16_s20200010100216_e20200010109524_c20200010110376.nc cada um deles geram uma matriz binária. 0 = sem nuvens e 1 = com nuvens.

aqui está uma pasta com arquivos netCDFs para poder executar o script:
[link da pasta no drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1OJXmw8Fwotzuy5AATq62B-YjoXe58dv5?usp=sharing)

Comment: É dificil dizer oque está acontecendo aí  - mas a parte do seu código que le os nmes dos arquivos e passa esses nomes para a função `interpreta` está bem...pareceuqe feita na tentativa e erro, sem se ter a menor ideia do que você está sendo feito até parar de dar erro. (pdrões de código completamente estranhos ao Python,  como colocar um `str()` para um objeto que já é uma string, concatenar texto com "+") e estranhos a qualquer lógica (adicionar `_SEC` ao nome do arquivo para remover de novo na linha seguinte).

Isso é sinal de que o mesmo acontece nas outras partes do código.

Comment: Talvez seja o caso de convidar uma pessoa que conheça a linguagem - pelo menos até ao ponto de poder ligar um depurador e acompanhar passo a passo, além de limpar essa parte da seleção dos arquivos, para acompanhar o processo de vocês. A parte de manipulação de arquivos é tranquila, quem sabe Python bate um olho e vê. A outra parte so é possível  verificar estando com a mão na massa - tendo os dados, etc... A pergunta, apesar de ter o código e a mensagem de erro completa, não tem nenhuma fonte de dados - o que faz com que não seja um exemplo mínimo reprodutível.

Comment: Esse mesmo programa chegou a rodar - e funcionar - para arquivos diferentes de entrada?

Comment: Olá, adicionei um link com uma pasta cheia de arquivos netCDFs para poder tornar reproduzível. O script não funcionaria com outros tipos de produtos, porém eu executei esse script numa pasta com mais de 1000 arquivos ACMF netCDF's e todos foram lidos e somados nas matrizes, o problema está somente na função countour().